# Хочу понять логику условия switch и значения в case

Tags: javascript, if, switch

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.field.length; i++) {
            let f = this.field;
            if (
                f[0].innerHTML == 'X' && f[1].innerHTML == 'X' && f[2].innerHTML == 'X' ||
                f[3].innerHTML == 'X' && f[4].innerHTML == 'X' && f[5].innerHTML == 'X' ||
                f[6].innerHTML == 'X' && f[7].innerHTML == 'X' && f[8].innerHTML == 'X' ||

                f[0].innerHTML == 'X' && f[3].innerHTML == 'X' && f[6].innerHTML == 'X' ||
                f[1].innerHTML == 'X' && f[4].innerHTML == 'X' && f[7].innerHTML == 'X' ||
                f[2].innerHTML == 'X' && f[5].innerHTML == 'X' && f[8].innerHTML == 'X' ||

                f[0].innerHTML == 'X' && f[4].innerHTML == 'X' && f[8].innerHTML == 'X' ||
                f[2].innerHTML == 'X' && f[4].innerHTML == 'X' && f[6].innerHTML == 'X'
            ) {
                console.log('x win')
```

подскажите как переделать с if на switch

```
 for(let i = 0; i<this.field.length; i++){
           switch(this.field[i]){
               case (this.field[0].innerHTML == 'X' && this.field[1].innerHTML == 'X' &&this.field[2].innerHTML == 'X'):
               console.log('asd');
               break;
           }
       }
```

пробовал что типа такого, но сам switch явно не должен принимать в параметр итый элемент... тогда что?

Comment: интересные у вас крестики нолики)))

Comment: аргумент для case результат вычисления switch

Comment: да замутил шаблонные строки через eval, но пришел к выводу что через switch тут не решишь задачу, он не достаточно гибок в циклах, или я ошибаюсь ?

Comment: покажите пжл. ваше решение, в ответе своего вопроса

Comment: у вас в условии if просматривается статичный цикл, это не есть симпатично)

Comment: скинул, еще не доделал, но приколяха с eval жесткая... =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте так

```js
   for(let i = 0; i<this.field.length; i++){
   switch(this.field[i].innerHTML + this.field[++i].innerHTML + this.field[++i].innerHTML){
      case 'XXX':{
        console.log('asd');
      };break;
      default:{ 
      console.log('не XXX');
   };break;
    }
 }
```

Comment: да это бы сработало, но дело в том что мне еще нужна проверка на несколько &&

Comment: вот можно так , поправил условие switch

Answer (score 1):

```
helperX(i) {
        return eval(`this.field[${i}].innerHTML == 'X' && this.field[${i + 1}].innerHTML == 'X' && this.field[${i + 2}].innerHTML == 'X'`)
    }

    helperY(i) {
        return eval(`this.field[${i}].innerHTML == 'X' && this.field[${i + 3}].innerHTML == 'X' && this.field[${i + 6}].innerHTML == 'X'`)
    }

    styleX(i){
        return eval(`this.field[${i}].style.color = 'red'; this.field[${i+1}].style.color = 'red'; this.field[${i+2}].style.color = 'red';`)
    }
    styleY(i){
        return eval(`this.field[${i}].style.color = 'red'; this.field[${i+3}].style.color = 'red'; this.field[${i+6}].style.color = 'red';`)
    }


    step(domElement) {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.field.length; i++) {
            if (domElement == this.field[i] && this.flag % 2 == 0 && this.field[i].innerHTML == '') {
                this.field[i].innerHTML = 'X';
                this.arr.push(this.field[i])
                this.flag++
            } else if (domElement == this.field[i] && this.field[i].innerHTML == '') {
                this.field[i].innerHTML = 'O';
                this.arr.push(this.field[i])
                this.flag++
            }
        }

    }

    checkWin() {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.field.length; i++) {
            if (this.helperX(0)) {
                this.styleX(0);
            } else if (this.helperX(3)) {
                this.styleX(3);
            }else if (this.helperX(6)) {
                this.styleX(6);
            }else if (this.helperY(0)) {
                this.styleY(0);
            }else if (this.helperY(1)) {
                this.styleY(1)
            }else if (this.helperY(2)) {
                this.styleY(2);
            }



        }
```

Comment: ответил выше, вы от свитч этого хотели

Comment: а лучше оформите в вопросе дом модель, чтобы лучше понять что вы ищете